# Cannot get activeadmin to load /admin page (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Using Rails 3.2.6 and activeadmin 0.5.1

Followed instructions at [site home page](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html) until `localhost:3000/admin` gives the following error

`ActionController::RoutingError (wrong constant name Admin/dashboardController)`

Strange part:

Source code of the gem has the following lines:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Dashboards
    module DashboardController
```

which should mean

`ActiveAdmin::Dashboards::DashboardController` should be available in the rails console.

Its not. here is the o/p

```
1.9.3p194 :045 > ActiveAdmin::Dashboards.DashboardController
NoMethodError: undefined method `DashboardController' 
for ActiveAdmin::Dashboards:Module
```

Ideas?

Comment: The lowercase `d` in "dashboard" in your error message is a red flag. What does your `routes.rb` file look like?

Comment: Also your console entry failed because you put a `.` instead of `::` in between the last two. DashboardController is a module not a method. Try `ActiveAdmin::Dashboards::DashboardController` to see if it recognizes that.

Comment: Routes has only these sections corresponding to admin.    `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config`